# Disallow formatting a USB drive encrypted with BitLocker To Go

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I recently encountered an issue with Microsoft BitLocker To Go and seek assistance finding a solution.

I discovered that there is nothing preventing a USB drive, encrypted with BitLocker To Go, from being reformatted, resulting in the loss of all existing user data, including the encrypted content. I have confirmed this behavior in Windows 11, 10, and 7.

Is there a way to disable the reformatting of a USB drive, encrypted with BitLocker To Go, without the decryption key?

This would benefit users who value data security, preventing the accidental loss of important information.

Comment: Encryption is intended to prevent unauthorized access to your unencrypted data, not to prevent "accidental loss of important information." If that is really of any concern to you then it should be part of your backup plan.  What will you do when the drive fails, or is lost or stolen?

Comment: "Is there a way to disable the reformatting of a USB drive, encrypted with BitLocker To Go, without the decryption key?" - No; There is nothing you can do, to prevent a system administrator on their own machine, from formatting your USB drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. There cannot be a software solution that prevents overwriting storage devices. Software protection cannot be enforced on systems you do not control.

The only way you could protect data from deletion is using hardware support. The storage device itself must deny writing. There are USB hard drives and flash drives that have built-in encryption, only granting access when unlocked. They usually have a PIN pad or a fingerprint scanner. Security varies greatly.

In the end, your solution against data loss must include multiple redundant backups, multiple physical locations and physical security in those locations, all in addition to software encryption.

Comment: @TM24_sense *Encryption* really just "locks" your *data*, not your *drive*. Strictly speaking even for hardware implementation, encryption and drive lock does not necessarily imply that the other is also implemented. It's just *often* the case so that you get some "real" / "all-round" protection.

Comment: If the drive were to only be used on windows operating systems can windows block the drive from being formatted?

Comment: No, as mentioned in the first paragraph, this is not possible.

Comment: Windows will not allow you to format some partition types.  Note that this first assumes that you have a partition table on your USB stick (i.e. not configured as "superfloppy").  And then there will be nothing stopping someone from changing the partitions (but this is much less likely to happen accidentally).

Comment: Even the drives that support physical encryption process (i.e. keypad or biometric authentication), when the volume is mounted within the operating system, all bets are off at that point.